# R markup Loading more than one package

Tags: r, markup

I need to load two packages to make all my calculations and create a document by using r mark-up. For this I have this code:

```
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
```

But when I use knit Word to build my document I get this in text:

```
## 
## Attaching package: 'dplyr'
## 
## The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
## 
##     filter
## 
## The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
## 
##     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

Any clues on what I can do to get rid of this, without stop loading it?

If I call only one library it works fine, but I need to call two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the chunk options to `{r, message = FALSE}`. `knitr` has many features to manipulate how much code/output is displayed. See http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/

Comment: Perfect ribo, many thanks! I was using echo=FALSE, didnt knew there was a message=FALSE also. Will study knitr deeper.